# Invoke a page by onclick() event using webdriver(selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to invoke the page based on the `onclick` event using a web driver(selenium).

`<img src="active.png" class="default-logo avatar-image" onclick="custom(event)">`

So can anybody help me with the solution it will be great.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Check the answer. Is this what you are looking for? That's what I understood from your description.

Comment: Yes, the solution is correct but it's not working in my case.
Here's is the code which I'm trying
```WebElement launchBot = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[onclick*=customHideMinimizedState(event)]"));;
launchBot.click();```

Comment: Upload the site you are testing and your source code so I can try it :)

Comment: I got the solution. basically we need to find the right element which is available in the page source. I did with the image id

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample as an example:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[onclick*=custom(event)]").click();
```

In this way, you will find an element type of img that has *onclick* attribute that *contains* (this is what ***=** means) this: *custom(event)*.